# IOS ADAL framework keep me sign in page is not appearing

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, adal

```
func loginWithADAL(account: Account, completion: @escaping(_ response: ADAuthenticationResult) -> Void) {
    //
    let clientID = account.appId
    defaults.set(clientID, forKey: kClientId)
    // let applicationID = eeaa6cd8-0aab-4108-bbc0-1c94bf8c25f5
    guard let url = URL(string: kRedirectUrl) else {return}
    //
    guard let domain = account.domain else { return }
    let authority = kAuthority + domain
    let authContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authority, error: &authenticationError)
    //
    let azureMail = defaults.value(forKey: kAzureMail) as? String ?? nil
    Utilities.hideHud()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        authContext?.acquireToken(withResource: kGraphURI, clientId: clientID, redirectUri: url, userId: azureMail, completionBlock: { (result) in
            if result?.error == nil {
                guard let data = result else { return }
                completion(data)
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.removeIndicatorLayer()
                }
                if let remember = defaults.value(forKey: kRememberMe) as? Bool, remember {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.closeSSOLogin()
                    }
                }
                if let error = result?.error.code, error == 211 {
                    self.showAlert(message: kDomainMismatch)
                } else if let error = result?.error.code, error == 204 {
                    self.removeCookies()
                    self.showAlert(message: kInvalidUser)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In my project(IOS APP) its a requirement to use Azure. But i don't know why the keep me sign in page is not appearing. I'm using acquire token API for log in.

Already went through ADAL library but no mention of it.

In log's i can see the error in loading URL. 
.<15> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey= Some Url}

Comment: You don't get that prompt. You simply store the token and call the refresh endpoint as required to update the token. At some point the refresh limit will be reached and you will need to perform an interactive login again

Comment: I'm getting the refresh token. But i need that page also to come up, as its a requirement. But why it's not loading that page its failing to load that URL. Is there any setting that will help me? @Paulw11

Comment: I have never seen that screen in an application authorisation flow; It doesn't make sense since it isn't a web app; Your app is responsible for either disposing of the token or keeping it.  You could create a screen in your app that asks the user if they want to stay logged in.

Comment: It is there. Some other people have already did it but i wonder how they did it. Because there's no proper documentation. And as far as token is concerned don't worry about it it will be handled. But do you know why is that pages URL is failing because the same thing is being implemented by others and our client is expecting same from us if u could help us then please. @Paulw11

Comment: It is an azure AD setting, not a client setting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime

Comment: But the client is saying this is globally enabled. For different apps with the same account the page is coming but not in our app.

Comment: Can you you show the code you are using with ADAL. Are you using SFSafariViewController?  Have you implemented its delegate?  As far as I know only the delegate can cancel navigation.  Is the client using the Microsoft Authenticator app? Does your authentication process open that app?

Comment: I'm using ADAL library above i've updated my question with code. I'm calling frameworks methods.

Comment: I'm not sure. Are those other apps using the ADALios framework?  I have never seen that prompt when using ADALios, only when using web based authentication.

Comment: Actually even i don't know what they are using. But are you sure that while using ADAL that page is not going to come??

Comment: I have never seen that page when using ADAL, only when logging in with a web application.

Comment: And also can You tell me if i wan't some how to implement that thing then what can i do for that. Also will it be secure enough for ex: if i rely on cookies? Please tell me a proper approach to implement that.